# Server Error 500 - installing Joomla

Tags: joomla, mamp, server-error

I'm trying to install Joomla 3.4.2 but when I go to my localhost to proceed with the installation it gives me a "Server Error 500". Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Check the error logs on the server - they will probably tell you something. Also, check that the server you are trying to install Joomla 3 on meets the minimum requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla don't support PHP7. You need to use Joomla 3.5 version.